# Is there any Emacs built-in to list the keys of an associton list?

Tags: association-lists

I could not find any function to list the keys of an associton list in Emacs documentation. So I wrote a simple one.

```
(defun my/keys (alist)
    "Return the keys of the given ALIST."
    (let ((value nil)
                (result-list ()))
    (dolist (value alist result-list)
        (setq result-list (cons (car value) result-list)))))
```

For which the following test evaluates true:

```
(ert-deftest keys-test ()
    (should (equal (my/keys '((key1 . "foo")
                              ("key2" . "bar")
                              (1 . "bazz")))
                             ;; result:
                             '(1 "key2" key1))))
```

I do not like reinventing the well are there any Emacs built-in function analogues with mine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a built-in for that, hence why libraries like [kv.el](https://github.com/nicferrier/emacs-kv) have been written.  Your code can be significantly simplified though:

```
(defun alist-keys (alist)
  (mapcar 'car alist))
```

Comment: What about `map-keys` from map.el .

Comment: Hm, didn't check for that one. Feel free to write another answer!